# DNS, Nameserver(s), Virtualmin/Webmin Configuration with GoDaddy

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver, webmin

I'm in the process of migrating all of my websites and DNS to my own local webserver. I've opted to use Webmin/Virtualmin after trying out all the various Open Source options. I'm having some trouble getting my Nameserver, Host Records and DNS straightened out.

Prior to my attempted switch, I had/have a majority of my domains registered with GoDaddy. Most of them still are.

I am currently attempting to use two of them in my configuration and we'll refer to them as follows:

**My "Company" Site**: domain1.com
**My "Host"ing Site**: domain2.com

### **Current GoDaddy Configuration for domain2.com:**

*In DNS Management -> Host Names:*
**ns1.domain2.com** points to my ***primary*** static public IP address.
**ns2.domain2.com** points to my ***secondary*** static public IP address.

*In DNS Management -> Nameservers*:
The nameservers for **domain2.com** are pointed at:
***ns1.domain2.com***
***ns2.domain2.com***.

### **Current GoDaddy Configuration for domain1.com:**

*In DNS Management -> Nameservers*:
ns1.domain2.com
ns2.domain2.com

The nameservers for **domain1.com** are pointed at:
 ***ns1.domain2.com***
***ns2.domain2.com***.

## The Issue

I can resolve the websites when browsing to them. They show the default virtualmin pages. However, I cannot issue any SSL's as apparently the DNS is not resolving. All DNS is configured as it was from the default VirtualMin Install Process and Walkthrough. The only thing I added was my Protonmail Domain Verification records to domain1.com so I can receive email again... However, they're not resolving.

### Here's what dns.google.com returns when I run a check for **domain1.com**

```
 {
      "Status": 2,
      "TC": false,
      "RD": true,
      "RA": true,
      "AD": false,
      "CD": false,
      "Question": [
        {
          "name": "domain1.com.",
          "type": 1
        }
      ],
      "Additional": []
    }
```

### Here's what dns.google.com returns when I run a check for **domain2.com**:

```
{
  "Status": 2,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "domain2.com.",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Additional": [],
  "Comment": "Name servers did not respond [xx.xx.xx.01, xx.xx.xx.02]."
}
```

It's been a day, so I would think things have propogated correctly, but it appears not.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've done quite a few hours of research trying to resolve this on my own... but I'm at a loss.

TIA!

Edit: All appropriate ports are open on my firewall (pfSense).
25,53,853,80,443,21,22,465,110,143,20000,10000

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. This nasty trick of binding 2 IP addresses to the same nameserver defeats the whole point of multiple nameservers and arguably breaks the DNS specification. Use your domain providers nameservers instead. (Also, Normally it would be appropriate to advise the domain name so we can run checks on it .).

Comment: The list of ports you claim to have open would also be frowned upon by a competent administrator.  I do note that you did not specify the protocol associated with the ports. For all ports you need TCP, but are you aware you need UDP port 53 as well for DNS.

Comment: I concur with davidgo.   If you are going to run DNS servers, you should have actual redundancy.  Ideally you would have three or four servers on separate continents.  The host names of the servers themselves should be under different top level domains.  Ie `ns101.example.com`, `ns102.example.org`, `ns103.example.eu`.   If you are not going to do it right, you are doing a disservice any customers of your hosting company and you should have your customers use the DNS services of another company that does it right.

Comment: Okay, I'm just going to scrap the DNS idea and revert back to Cloudflare. Thank you for the input everyone.

In the meantime, I guess I need to better understand DNS.